# Deactivate SYN flooding mechanism

Tags: tcp

I am running a server that is running a service on port 59380. There are more than 1000 machines out there connecting to that service. Once I need to restart the service all those machines are connecting at the same time.

That made some trouble as I have seen that log entry in kern.log

```
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 59380. *Sending cookies*.  Check SNMP counters.
```

So I changed sysctl `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies` to 0 because the endpoints to not handle tcp syn cookies correctly. Finally I restarted my network to get the changes in production

Next time I had to restart the service, the following message was logged

```
TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 59380. *Dropping request*.  Check SNMP counters.
```

How can I prevent the system for doing such actions? All necessary counter measures are done by iptables...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Do not** disable SYN cookies, that is incredibly counter-productive, as you can see, instead of the host falling back to cookie'd sockets, it simply drops it.

The correct thing to do is adjust `net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog` to a high enough value that it no longer fires this warning.

You will probably also want to adjust the TCP stack in general to have more memory - a cursory Google for "Linux TCP Tuning" should provide what you need.

Comment: It should be noted that 65535 is the maximum possible value.

Comment: It should also be noted that in the `listen` man page, it says: "When syncookies are enabled there is no logical maximum length and this setting [tcp_max_syn_backlog] is ignored.  See tcp(7) for more information."

Answer (score 0):

Also read following pages . Maybe should check again .

http://lwn.net/Articles/277146/

https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/2/5/167